# How to change case details page default view

Tags: case, page-layout

When ever I click on the case am getting Feed view as the default view and I do not want this.I need the details page as my default view.

Is it possible to make the details view as the default view...?

Thanks
Chitra

Answer (score 8):

Finally I have fixed it...Thanks to [bob_buzzard](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsProfile?communityId=09aF00000004HMG&userId=005F0000003Fbch&showHeader=false) ...
The case feed is enabled via the Setup -> Customize -> Cases -> Support Settings -> Enable Case Feed Actions and Feed Items.
Once this is checked, users have the case feed view or regular record view based on the "Use Case Feed" setting in their profile or assigned permission set.

I have just disabled this option.Once disabled it,I was getting Feed & Details view in a single page with a link to hide the feed.So it can be Hide/Show based on the end user need.Once the user Hide Feed it will not be expanded automatically next time.

Cheers...

Comment: You should mark it as answer. So that others will know this as a correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to setup->Cases -> page layout

Click 'Page Layout Assignment'

Click 'Edit Assignment'

Assign the required page layout to your profile and click save.

you should be all set.

Comment: Hi Raj,
Thank you for your quick reply.But your suggestion leads me to select default layout..But my query is am getting case layout..In that layout 2 views are there.Feed & Details view.By default Feed view is coming,I need to change the default view to details.
Thanks