# is it possible to change the default behaviour of the feed based page layout

Tags: page-layout, configuration, chatter-feed, feed-based-layout

I have set up a new page layouot which uses the feed based layout. Is it possible to configure the page to default to the "Details" tab of the page layout as opposed to the feed?
[image]

Comment: did you check this discussion - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46652/how-to-change-case-details-page-default-view/46669#46669

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot find any official documentation on this but, AFAIK, this is not possible.  I did find an idea for this functionality though.  Also found a blog post on feed based layouts where the poster suggests (in a comment at the bottom) that they also do not believe its possible to change details to the default.

IDEA

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l6E9AAI

Blog Post

http://rakeshistom.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/feed-based-page-layouts/

Love to see if someone found some actual documentation that clearly states it is not possible.

Comment: i just voted for that idea :-)

Comment: Just voted it up as well.

Comment: What's sad is... that Idea will no longer be paid attention to, because it's "been Delivered"................. in Lightning, which is useless to those of us not capable or desiring to use Lightning (or using Rootstock and other products which are BROKEN by Lightning being enabled).   >:-(

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that the last tab you switched to is set as default. So everytime you change tabs the default keeps changing. This was tested on a custom object.

Comment: This is not the answer. Please post your comments in appropriate section.

Comment: I think this is relevant information. It's a bit light, but it may not be noticed as a comment.

Comment: This is not my experience.   I see that "eventually" (have not tested but know it happens from daily use) it DOES return to the default "Feed tab FIRST" methodology.  I am unclear if it's per Object, or per Record.  It DOES eventually go back to loading the Feed, FIRST but not right away.

Answer (score 0):

An update on this - its possible and has been delivered. However, the catch is its only possible lightning. Obviously an effort for SFDC to try an migrate more customers over to lightning.

Comment: May you also add a reference for your findings?

Answer (score -1):

The default tab when first logging into Salesforce will always be the Feed tab for Feed Based layouts. If you then select Details on a record then it will remember via a cookie in your web browser. But cookies will expire as soon as the session ends and the browsers are closed.